# How to update Persistent volume claim programmatically

Tags: python, kubernetes

I am partly new to Kubernetes advance concepts. I have PersistentVolume, PersistentVolumeClaim  and a Pod using this Claim. This is example of static provisioning. I have now installed CSI driver and have storage class "managed-csi-class" which uses this CSI driver. I wat to update this setup to dynamic provisioning. Using Python script, i tried to update Persistent volume claim. Below program returns output as "---updated----". But the claim storage class still remains as "Manual". At this stage, i tried to update the PersistentVolumeClaim Manually to update its "storageClassName" but it dosent allow me to do so. I tried deleting the Pod but still same issue.  Any idea what else needs to be done to update PersistentVolumeClaim's storage class  ?

```
v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
body = {"spec": {"storageClassName": "managed-csi-class"}}
    try:
        api_response = v1.patch_namespaced_persistent_volume_claim('static-pv-claim', 'testnamespace', body, async_req=True)
        print("---updated----")
        print(api_response)
    except ApiException as e:
        print("Exception when calling CoreV1Api->patch_namespaced_persistent_volume_claim: %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: You need to delete the claim and recreate it, while recreating put the new storageclass name. To know more about dynamic provisioning of storageclass name refer this [link](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/03/dynamic-provisioning-and-storage-classes-kubernetes/)

Comment: Hi @DharaniDharGolladasari, so you mean after deleting PVC, i need to recreate PVC with same name but different storage class and even Pod i need to recreate ?

Comment: Hi @HotDev Yes after recreating the PVC with new storageclass then  redeploy the pods

Comment: ok @DharaniDharGolladasari. I will consider this way. Also i dint get in above code snippet, why i see  output as "---updated----". It should have thrown exception correct ? any idea ?